# Android PDF scrollview single continuous page

Tags: java, android, pdf, scroll

In xcode I can display a PDF as a single continuous page, with the PDF width being equal to screen width and then the vertical scroll being the height of PDF for said width. No problems

Currently converting same app to Android and having some difficulty implementing same PDF view

Basically I have a PDF page that is very long (single page). I don't want to swipe between pages, but instead like in my iOS app, have the PDF document fill the Android screen width wise, and then scroll vertically to show rest of PDF

I'm using com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView to render my PDF

In my xml for the activity I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            tools:context=".ProfileActivity">

                <LinearLayout
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
                             android:id="@+id/pdfView"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I've tried changing the layout_height to "wrap_content" for scrollView, Linear and pdf, as that would seem appropriate, but whenever I do this I get a blank screen. It seems that doing so resulting in no height attribute so the view collapses completely

I get: [image: Android screen]

What I want: [image: iOS Screen - which scrolls to show rest of PDF]

Would really appreciate any further help, this is really my only sticking point. I wish android had PDFKit (similar) as I found that quite easy to use and implement

Comment: PSPDFKit appears [to have continuous-vertical-scroll capability](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/android/current/customizing-the-interface/document-presentation-options/). Alternatively, perhaps your content should be represented as a single Web page, which you would render with a `WebView`.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I would rather not use PSPDFKit due to charges. In regard to WebView, please could you expand?

Comment: Well, Web pages naturally operate in a continuously-vertical-scrollable mode. For example, scroll this Web page. Perhaps your content could be in HTML/CSS/JS instead of PDF format.

Comment: Sorry but what a ridiculous comment....the question is specifically about PDF, why on earth would I change the content to HTML.. literally nothing to do with the question, just wasting my time. If I could downvoted a comment I would a thousand times

Comment: "why on earth would I change the content to HTML" -- because it fits your desired rendering pattern, and it is free of charge. So now you are seeking a solution where you are forcing a content format, a rendering pattern, and a price point. Do not be surprised if you wind up having to implement much lower-level stuff to accomplish that combination, such as contributing patches to the open source library that you are trying to use, if there is no built-in option for continuous vertical scrolling.

Comment: Fair enough on your response, apologies for my previous comment if rude. Unfortunately I've seen comments previously that have no relation to the question and I find it infuriating. However, ultimately the question is that I'm seeking a solution similar to PDFkit in Android. I would be very surprised to find out that such rendering is not possible. I have over 100 PDF's so changing to HTML unfortunately is not an option

Comment: I presume the issue I'm having is a layout constraint issue, where I need to set the PDF to width of the view, and then the view height to conform to the PDF at that width. Whereas at present the opposite is happening, it is setting the PDF to the height of the view, and then conforming the width to the PDF at that height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is an answer!

I had to 'upgrade' to the latest version: 3.1.0-beta.1 and use the:

```
.pageFitPolicy(FitPolicy.WIDTH)
```

Combined with my XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        tools:context=".AboutActivity">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Worked perfectly. I hope this helps others